# Custom Suffixes for Sub-compounds in chemnum

Tags: chemistry, chemnum

I'm using chemnum to keep track of my compounds in my thesis, and there are certain instances where I have a group of compounds that differ by a single substituent. Ideally, I would like to be able to define the suffixes used for subcompounds like so:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemnum} 
\setchemnum{replace-style=\bfseries} 

\begin{document} 
A class of compounds \cmpd{substituted} can have several R groups as substituents. 
I would like \cmpd{substituted.methyl} and \cmpd{substituted.phenyl} to appear as 
\cmpd{substituted}$\cdot$Me and \cmpd{substituted}$\cdot$Ph both here in the text 
and when using \replacecmpd{} with my .ps files. 
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to edit the counter representation when declaring a subcompound? Or can it be edited after subcompound declaration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know **nothing** about `chemnum` and **EVEN LESS** about LaTeX3.  But since the package is written in LaTeX3, I played with things a bit, and came up with...something.  It doesn't answer your question fully, but may give you ideas on how to proceed.

I created a new label format called `cmd` that calls upon `\blah:n` and made `cmd` the default representation for sub-counters.  The `\blah:n` macro takes an argument, converts it to `Alph` and wraps a `\csname` around it, so that the first substituent is defined with `\CMDA`, the second with `\CMDB`, etc.  How to make this work across different primary groups etc. is well beyond the scope of my knowledge.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{chemnum} 
\setchemnum{replace-style=\bfseries}
\def\CMDA{$\cdot$Me}
\def\CMDB{$\cdot$Ph} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \blah:n #1 {\cs:w CMD\int_to_Alph:n #1\cs_end:}
\newcmpdcounterformat {cmd}   { \blah:n }
\tl_set:Nn
            \l__chemnum_default_subcounter_representation_tl
            {cmd}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document} 
\section{First}

A class of compounds \cmpd{substituted} can have several R groups as substituents. 
I would like \cmpd{substituted.methyl} and \cmpd{substituted.phenyl} to appear as 
\cmpd{substituted}$\cdot$Me and \cmpd{substituted}$\cdot$Ph both here in the text 
and when using \replacecmpd{} with my .ps files. 

\end{document}
```

[image]